# Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, libraries

I have problem with imagick php extension. When trying to manipulate jpeg files error occurs:

> Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80

I was trying to find where that library is istalled with:

```
# ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```

and

```
# whereis libjpeg
libjpeg: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
```

phpinfo() shows:

```
libJPEG Version 6b
```

in "gd" section

I have also tried to install both libjpeg8 and libjpeg8-dev via apt-get, it says its already installed:

```
libjpeg8 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

libjpeg8-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm running:

- Debian 7.9
- Apache/2.4.17 (Unix)
- PHP 5.5.30 (cli) Zend Engine v2.5.0,
- Imagick 3.1.2

I'm really confused - i've search google but nothing helped. What should I do?

Comment: Where did you get PHP and imagick from?

Comment: did you removed libjpeg6 ?

Comment: @Michael Hampton 
php form custombuild (i'm using directadmin)
imagick via apt-get install php5-imagick

Comment: That won't work. You need to build imagick support into your custom PHP build.

Comment: Thank you anyway, that advice was helpful. Sorry for offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP version is showing that you are using `libJPEG Version 6b` and you need the version 8 to have it works

Make a clean install:

You need to uninstall libjpeg version 6 & 8

```
apt-get remove libjpeg6
apt-get remove libjpeg8
apt-get autoremove
```

and install version 8 after

```
apt-get install libjpeg8
```

Comment: Yes, i've removed libjpeg 6:
' #apt-get remove libjpeg6'
' # E: Unable to locate package libjpeg6'

Comment: You need to make it clean : remove both 6 & 8 then launch autoremove to clean dependencies, then reinstall libjpeg8.

Comment: I think this is a really bad suggestion, there's plenty of stuff depending on those libs.